# Do traded players get their names on the Stanley Cup if previous team wins?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, stanley-cup

So, I would assume the answer to this question is "No", but I can't actually verify it anywhere.  The criteria for getting your name on the cup is to play at least 41 regular season games for the cup winning team.  But if a player is traded after that 41 games, is his name still engraved on the Cup even though he played out the season with another team?

Comment: Okay, I think I've answered my own question.  No, because Cam Barker played 51 games for Chicago in the 2009-2010 season before being traded to Minnesota.  His name does not appear on the cup.

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_VIzeHgMtkks/TKUw4ndFl-I/AAAAAAAACOs/oXB_xRmXZeI/s1600/STanley+Cup+Engraved.jpg

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly legitimate; feel free to move that comment into an answer.

Comment: Not only legitimate, it's even encouraged! Although I'm going to add the NHL tag as this is not necessarily the case in all Ice Hockey.

Answer (score 10):

According to [this article](http://proicehockey.about.com/od/stanleycupbunker/f/stanley_cup_nam.htm):

> Prior to 1977 only players who had completed the Stanley Cup playoffs
>   were eligible. Today, players appearing in 41 regular-season games or
>   one Stanley Cup Final game for the championship team have their names
>   engraved on the Cup. The NHL makes exceptions for players who do not
>   meet the standard because of injury or other extenuating
>   circumstances.

And according to [the NHL](http://www.nhl.com/cup/fun_facts.html):

> To have one's name engraved on the Stanley Cup certain requirements
>   must be met. A player must have at least 41 games played with the club
>   or one game played in the Stanley Cup Finals. **However, in 1994 a
>   stipulation was added to allow a team to petition the Commissioner for
>   permission to have players' names put on the Cup if extenuating
>   circumstances prevented them from being available to play.**

However, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Cup):

> The Detroit Red Wings received special permission from the NHL to
>   inscribe the name of Vladimir Konstantinov, whose career ended after a
>   car accident on June 13, 1997, on the Stanley Cup after Detroit
>   defended their title in 1998.

So it appears that player traded away could be added in theory, but probably not in practice.

Comment: `Today, players appearing in 41 regular-season games or one Stanley Cup Final game for the championship team have their names engraved on the Cup` seems to indicate the player traded away after 41 games *would* be added.  Your conclusion doesn't seem to be supported?

Comment: @matthew, from the context, the 41 games rule was in effect if the player was still with the organization when the Stanley Cup was won.

Comment: This does raise the question: if a player was so instrumental to the team that you would add them to the cup, why would you trade him?

Comment: @corsiKa, some possible reasons might include acquiring another key player at a position of need or building depth for the playoff run.